# How to check if .realm database already exists?

Tags: android, realm

I want to check if my xyz.realm database already exists, any ideas on how tackle this?

Comment: Could you post some code about what you tried so far?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
RealmConfiguration config = getConfig();
if (new File(config.getPath()).exists()) {
  // exists
} else {
  // don't exists
}
```

Comment: Thanx sir, it perfectly works. Isn't there another way provided within the Realm API?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String defaultName = Realm.getDefaultInstance().getConfiguration().getRealmFileName();
                if("xyz.realm".equals(defaultName)){
                    //TODO
                }else{
                    //TODO
                }
```

Comment: That won't work. `getRealmFileName()` only return the name of the realm file, not the complete path, so you are just comparing the names of possible file. Not the actual files on disk.